# Save hexbinplot to object

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, lattice

Is there a way to assign a plot of hexbin data to an object?

```
library(hexbin)
myData <- hexbin(rnorm(100),rnorm(100), xbins=50) 
myPlot <- plot(myData)
```

I would expect that showing the plot is suppressed and the object `myPlot` contains it.
However, calling `myPlot` just prints out a list.

Comment: Where does the `hexbin` function you are using come from? You should explicitly list any non-base R packages you are using. What exactly do you plan to do with the object if not print it?

Comment: What does `class(myPlot)` return? It is very common to see object classes implemented as objects of class `list`. (Sub-classing it.)

Comment: Assuming that's the hexbin package, it's a matter of how it uses grid. Getting it to work in ggplot is simpler: `ggplot(data.frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100)), aes(x, y)) + geom_hex(bins = 50)` You'll need a lot more data for it to look like much, though; try `rnorm(5000)` or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because calling `myPlot` just invokes `print.list(myPlot)`
since `plot(myData)` just returns a list. The only reason this works for lattice and ggplot2 is because they have `print()` methods defined for the objects that are returned from `plot()` method.

I don't see anything intrinsically wrong with storing the `myData` object and calling `plot()` whenever you need to produce the plot. Is there any use case where you need the particular functionality offered by automatic printing?

If you want to have output in the form of grid objects, you can try to use `grid::grid.grab()`

```
myData <- hexbin(rnorm(100),rnorm(100)) 
plot(myData)
grobs <- grid::grid.grab()
str(grobs)

[1] "gTree" "grob"  "gDesc"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply. My use case woulld be to call `grid.edit` to modify elements of the plot. That's why I would initially like to suppress the output and only print it out once I edited some of the elements.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I am looking for. Is there a way to then edit a child of the "gTree" to modify parts of the graph?

Comment: Yes, that is the point of the object. Check out the documentation for `grid::editGrob()`